# Selenium highlight working only on one specific machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Selenium code to highlight an element is working only on one of the system.
I have updated chrome and chrome driver on both of them but in one machine, it works but code breaks on another machine when trying to highlight the page element.
Below is the exception:

```
An error occurred while fetching element : Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: body_x_grid_x__ctl2__ctl0 (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '**', ip: '**', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab), userDataDir=**}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=67.0.3396.99, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 9854688adcdbe56519b9869c496b58e2
    at com.selenium.element.action.Wait.elementAction(Wait.java:68)
....
```

It does not find the element within specific periods and breaks.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
An error occurred while fetching element : Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: body_x_grid_x__ctl2__ctl0 (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '**', ip: '**', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to interact with the  **WebElement** returned after *WebDriverWait*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* and *ChromeDriver* versions are not getting detected back.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_77** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u77* and the latest *Selenium Client v3.13.0* , *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v67.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u172**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.13.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Keep *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.40**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.40 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Still not working after upgrading Java, Selenium and chrome browser version to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a `try`/`catch` clause, and inside the `catch` save the content of `webdriver.getPageSource()`. Then examine its content (you may even be able to open it in the browser if you name the file with a `.html` extension) and see whether an element with `id='body_x_grid_x__ctl2__ctl0'` actually exists.

I'm not sure, but it looks like this id was generated automatically by the application, and may be generated somewhat differently on the other machine.

Comment: Checked it. It exists on this page. This issue is system related but unable to find RC

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with highlighter, it's with your webElement:

```
An error occurred while fetching element : Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: body_x_grid_x__ctl2__ctl0 (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

Increase the wait time because your existing wait in 15 sec: increase according to your website page load maximum time:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, wait time in second);
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your xpath")));
```

After getting the webElement you can go for highlighter by using below code:

```
public void highLighter(WebDriver driver, WebElement we) {
        try{
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
          String var =  (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].getAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", we);
          js.executeScript("return arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", we,"border:4px solid red;");
          Thread.sleep(200);
          js.executeScript("return arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", we,var);
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("unable to HighLight");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same code is working on different machine running on same network.